# Visual Studio 2010 Database project scripts generated

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, database-project

I have a database project in Visual Studio and when I deploy it creates a series of scripts and executes them. The scripts seem to be tied to Visual Studio deployment though. I would like to be able to take the script and execute it in SQL Server Management Studio on the server. Is this possible?

Comment: @Tushar - I will keep an eye out.

Comment: I myself have been annoyed by the missing functionality in Visual Studio 2010. I have looked at various options/alternative to manage and deploy the scripts on the server, but nothing was as easy as it was in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to run the deployment TSQL script directly (although there may be some parameters required), but you would normally do this using VSDBCmd:

> GDR comes with a command-line tool
>   called VSDBCmd (vsdbcmd.exe). This
>   tool can create a .dbschema file from
>   an existing database and deploy a
>   build output or only a .dbschema file
>   to a target instance. VSDBCmd can also
>   be used on a computer on which Visual
>   Studio is not installed. To move the
>   command-line tool from one computer to
>   another, copy the executable and its
>   components from the Deploy directory
>   under the VSTSDB directory. In a
>   standard Visual Studio installation,
>   this will be "%programfiles%\microsoft
>   visual studio 9.0\vstsdb\deploy. The
>   Deploy directory can be copied onto a
>   thumb-drive and then placed on another
>   computer.

Ref: [Introducing New Features In The VSTS Database Edition GDR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483214.aspx)

Comment: This is good, but doesn't really fulfill the requirement to run the scripts in SSMS.

Comment: @Craig: suggest you take it up with Microsoft! Or you could supply those parameters yourself usinge setvar (there are only a handful)

Comment: Normally I just doctor the script like you say. It is pretty easy but would be good to have an option to not need to.